# what is the .from(20).fetch(10) from the below code in play framework

Tags: playframework-1.x

In this line of code,

```
List<User> users = User.find("byEmailLike", "alexander@%") .from(20).fetch(10);
```

what is the `.from(20).fetch(10)` ?

Answer (score 1):

It's intuitive usage: *fetch 10 records starting from 20*

Also it's described in docs, you should take a look **[there](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/jpa)**

```
List<Post> posts = Post.all().from(50).fetch(100); // 100 max posts start at 50
```